# Directional derivative along the intersection of two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can i find the intersection curve between these two surfaces
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 2x^2 + 2y^2 − z^2 &= 50\\
 x^2 + y^2 -z^2 &= 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I need it to find the directional derivative of $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 − z^2$, with this point $(3, 4, 5)$ and along the intersection curve mentioned above. I know how to get the gradient, I just don't know how to aproach finding that intersection.

Comment: I think the intersection curve can be found by subtracting the equations from each other, no? You can eliminate $z$ that way.

Comment: You can do this without finding an intersection. Just find normal vectors to both surfaces (i.e. compute gradients) and then compute theirs cross product to obtain curve tangent vector.

Comment: @Virtuoz So i use (3,4,5) to find normal vectors of each surface? 
for example for the first surface: 
4xi+4yj-2zk, then using(3,4,5) i would get
4(3)i+4(4)j-2(5)k=(12,16,-10)
Then normal vector would be(6sqrt(5)/25,8sqrt(5)/25,-sqrt(5)/5)
Then on to the second surface and then cross product of both? Is this correct?

Comment: @CalebCedeño I expanded my comment to the full answer. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without finding an intersection. Just find normal vectors to both surfaces (i.e. compute gradients) and then compute theirs cross product to obtain curve tangent vector.

For the first surface the gradient is
$$
(4x, 4y, -2z).
$$
The second one gives us
$$
(2x, 2x, -2z).
$$

So, we can take $(2x, 2y, -z)$ and $(x, y, -z)$ as normal vectors and compute their cross product to obtain tangent vector
$$
\boldsymbol{v} = \begin{vmatrix}
\boldsymbol{i} & \boldsymbol{j} &\boldsymbol{k} \\
2x & 2y & -z \\
x & y & -z
\end{vmatrix} = -yz \boldsymbol{i} +xz\boldsymbol{j}.
$$

Let's substitute $(3,4,5)$
$$
\boldsymbol{v} = -4\cdot 5\boldsymbol{i} + 3\cdot{5}\boldsymbol{j}.
$$
It's easy to see that normalizing this vector we get
$$
\boldsymbol{v}_1 = \frac{\boldsymbol{v}}{|\boldsymbol{v}|} = -\frac{4}{5} \boldsymbol{i} + \frac{3}{5}\boldsymbol{j}.
$$

Now you need to find the directional derivative along $\boldsymbol{v}_1$ or $-\boldsymbol{v}_1$ (both will be tangent vectors indicating two different directions on the curve).

The other way for solving this problem (as suggested in the comments) was to eliminate $z$ from the equations and get the curve (WLOG we take positive $z$ considering the case $z = -5\sqrt{2}$ by analogy)
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 50, \; z = 5\sqrt{2}.
$$
So, we see that the curve is a circle $x^2 + y^2 = 50$ located at the "height" $z=5\sqrt{2}$ (this actually explains why $k$ coordinate is equal to zero in tangent vector). The tangent vector to the circle
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 50
$$
is equal to $(-y, x)$ and after substitution we get again
$$
\boldsymbol{v} = (-4, 5) \implies \boldsymbol{v}_1 = \frac{\boldsymbol{v}}{|\boldsymbol{v}|} = -\frac{4}{5} \boldsymbol{i} + \frac{3}{5}\boldsymbol{j}.
$$

All you need now is to compute the directional derivative (i.e. to find dot product of gradient of the function and obtained unit vector).

Comment: for the last step (computing the directional derivative) for gradient of the function i got (6,8,-10), if I dot product that with (-4/5, 3/5) Its equaled to 0. Did i do something wrong? Or is it meant to be 0?

Comment: @CalebCedeño zero directional derivative is perfectly fine, it shows that function does not change in this direction. One more way to see it is to consider curve $x^2 + y^2 = C_1^2$, $z = C_2$. It's easy to see that function does not change along this curve and it equals to $C_1^2 - C_2^2$ anywhere on the curve. So indeed the derivative along this curve (i.e. along the tangent vector of the curve) should be zero.